# How to get mapped type of nested property in array item?

Tags: typescript

```js
const arr = [
  { key: 'one', value: '1' },
  { key: 'two', value: '2' },
  { key: 'three', value: '3' },
] as const;

type Keys = GetKeys<typeof arr>;
```

How to define `GetKeys` so that `Keys` would be be `'one' | 'two' | 'three'`?

Comment: Can you use built-in [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) (also called "indexed access type") a few times to get the numeric-keyed elements from the array and then the `"key"`-keyed properties of those:

```
type GetKeys<T extends readonly {key: any}[]> = T[number]['key'];

type Keys = GetKeys<typeof arr>;
// type Keys = "one" | "two" | "three"
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gKBjA3jAawFMBPALhgHJwjKAaGANzgBsBXIiygRkpgF862PIVJcoAdxD0mrDlwBMfQcPzFyVKAAsERWg2btOVAMzKhAXXgQYoSFADcmTFBIAHIjADiRKAGlSCAAeABUYIgAPKCIwABMbXThY8BYSPHUKODASfnQLAD5UGBD0MDYAWwAjIgQLdEp1SgsnF3dPAJIbNB9-QKDXDxAAM3gkfKcAegmYAfbAooAiGgWYAB8YBckQFfXNnT0FoA)